# Reading a file in Python for text

Tags: python

I am given

```
bus_stops0.txt    
01012,Victoria St,Hotel Grand Pacific
01013,Victoria St,St. Joseph's Ch
01019,Victoria St,Bras Basah Cplx
```

in a notepad and I have no idea how to open this file inside IDLE.

Also,
I want to define

```
def read_data(filename):
    stops = [] 
    with open(filename,  'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line[:-1]
            code, road_name, desc = line.split(',')
            stops.append(filename)
    return str(stops)
```

such that

```
read_data('bus_stops0.txt')
```

> ['01012,Victoria St,Hotel Grand Pacific', "01013,Victoria St,St. Joseph's Ch", '01019,Victoria St,Bras Basah Cplx']

Is my definition correct in the first place?

Comment: I don't see why you `line = line[:-1]`. Also, `stops.append(filename)` appends `filename` which is `'bus_stops0.txt'`. You probably want to `stops.append(line)`, given your output

Comment: How can you have "no idea how to open this file inside IDLE" when your next chunk of code *does exactly that*, using `open`? Have you considered *testing* that code to see what output it gives?

Comment: The problem is I am testing out the code inside a website that has already coded the file within. But if I want to see it on Idle itself, I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need the output something like this

```
['01012,Victoria St,Hotel Grand Pacific', "01013,Victoria St,St. Joseph's Ch", '01019,Victoria St,Bras Basah Cplx']
```

If that would be the case then here is the code. Make sure file has read permission.

```
def read_data(filename):
    stops = []
    with open(filename,  'r') as fobj:
       for line in fobj:
           stops.append(line.strip())
    return stops
```

Comment: This is the one! But what is the difference between my original and yours?

Comment: first of all what is the use of this `line = line[:-1]
            code, road_name, desc = line.split(',')` and 2nd thing is the append method it should `stops.append(line)` instead of `stops.append(filename)`. As clearly depicted by @njzk2

Answer (score 1):

for desired output the definition is:

```
def read_data(filename):
   stops = []
   with open(filename,  'r') as f:
       for line in f:
           stops.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
   return str(stops)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `U` flag for universal readlines mode.

```
def read_data(filename):
   stops = []
   with open(filename,  'rU') as f:
       for line in f:
           stops.append(line.strip())
   return stops
```

Alternately, you can simply return `readlines` if you want to preserve your newlines

```
def read_data(filename):
   with open(filename,  'rU') as f:
       return f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

If 'stops' are the third element for each file line and you want to use list comprehension:

```
def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename,  'r') as f:
        stops = [line.split(',')[-1] for line in f]
return str(stops)
```